# Tracking goals in Google Analytics content experiments

Tags: google, google-analytics

I seem to have a hard time getting goals to track properly in GA's content experiments.
I have my landing page which has the GA tracking code.

On the conversion page (this is on a *different domain* than my landing page), I have the following code below. This is my GA tracking code + calling gaq.push to track the goal.

Under conversions -> goals -> overview, I see "myconversion" being tracked correctly.

However, when I go to content -> experiments, I see no conversions being tracked.
(I made sure that the conversion being tracked for my experiments are also for "myconversion"

Am I missing anything here ?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'myconversion', 'product1', 'purchased']);
    </script>
```

To isolate the issue, I created another experiment with the goal that fires on an onclick event on the landing page, and that is being tracked correctly.